# Using bodyparser to create Postgres update on multiple rows

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, body-parser

Application built with Express and Postgres.

I'm using body-parser to get comma separated values from a form. Typically a query like this will work for updating one product in my table:

```
const sqlProdOrder = 'UPDATE product_index SET product_ordered = $2 WHERE product_id = $1';
```

However, now I'm trying to update multiple rows at the same time with different data. I saw a previous question and came to this conclusion, but I'm still getting a query error:

```
const sqlProdOrder = "WITH sample (product_id, product_ordered) AS ( SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY['$2'], ARRAY['$1'])) UPDATE product_index SET product_ordered = s.ordered FROM sample s WHERE product_id = s.id";
```

Here is the post with express:

```
router.post('/order', auth.check.bind(auth), (req, res) => {
const paramsProdOrderId = [req.body.product_id, req.body.product_ordered];
db.query(sqlProdOrder, paramsProdOrderId).then((results) => {
    if (results.rowCount === 0) {
        res.redirect('/products');
        return;
    }
    res.redirect('/');
})

.catch((err) => {
    res.redirect('/error/404')
});
```

});

Using both of the "sqlProdOrder" queries of course, results in me being send to the /error/404.

I've console logged the body-parser data and everything is coming through fine. I really that that the second example of "sqlProdOrder" would work.

I'd greatly appreciate help with this. I believe I need to use unnest, but I don't really know how to use it, as you can see by my example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, in short, use the first `sqlProdOrder` query which is the ideal way calling the update query.

> Blockquote

EDIT: I have used ANY for $1 since it is an array of integers.

```
router.post('/order', auth.check.bind(auth), (req, res) => {

  const { product_id, product_ordered } = req.body;

  db.query(
    'UPDATE product_index SET product_ordered = $2 WHERE product_id = ANY($1)',
    [product_id, product_ordered]
  )
    .then(results => {
      if (results.rowCount === 0) {
        res.redirect('/products');
        return;
      }
      res.redirect('/');
    })

    .catch(err => {
      res.redirect('/error/404');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I copy pasted the code you posted and it resulted in this error:

"{ error: invalid input syntax for integer: "{"76","81","82","90","91","92","93","99","103","107"}"


The integers being quoted there are the product_id's.

I got this to work:
const sqlProdOrder = "WITH sample (id, ordered) AS ( SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY[$2], ARRAY[$1])) UPDATE product_index SET product_ordered = s.ordered FROM sample s WHERE product_id = s.id";

however, it only works when I remove the $2 and $1 and use raw csv. I logged the body and it's fine. It wont interpret $1, $2

Comment: The answer you provided doesn't work, unfortunately. I get that invalud input syntax for the ID field.

When trying to make the second sqlProdOrder query work, I verified that the syntax is okay. However, the $1 and $2 variables are not being interpreted. I get an error saying that 'integer = text' and I assume it's because the required value is numeric. Which, would mean that $1 and $2 is not being translated in to comma separated numbers

Comment: @HarleySalas, are you telling me that product_id and product_ordered are comma separated values.

Comment: Here is me console logging the sql query, as well as the params(body-parsed data)

https://monosnap.com/file/uO4RmqobuM1V5e1RaLlnwefDR02l3T

Yes, they're comma separated. Multiple rows are being changed at the same time.

Comment: @HarleySalas, please use my code and console log both product_id and product_ordered. I am sure there is something really silly that is being missed.

Comment: @HarleySalas, check my edit and try tuning your code.

Comment: https://monosnap.com/file/93SOjS5AxwSLCu0VRONuNVKcG87cXd

I tried with ANY($2), then got the same error for $1. So, I tried ANY($1) as well

Comment: @HarleySalas looking at the image, looks like both  both product_id and product_ordered are not arrays. It simple looks like one large string. And that seems like the problem.